# Spring annotation @Request mapping throws error while parsing json

Tags: json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public  DealerData createData( @RequestBody Data data) {
    return data;
}
```

I am getting this exception when I pass the json into the function.

```
Exception: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure you are sending the correct JSON. e.g., Check if you did `stringify` to your js object
- Make sure your Data object is a correct POJO. e.g.,getters/setters are present.

Comment: I was missing my Getter and Setters.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure your HTTP request contains both `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers and their values must be `application/json`.

Besides it, you must ensure you request payload contains a JSON that matches the `Data` class.